# Tools for Feature Extraction from Binary Data of Images

Tags: validation, machine-learning, file-format, feature-extraction, fuzzing

I am working on a project where I am have image files that have been malformed (fuzzed i.e their image data have been altered). These files when rendered on various platforms lead to warning/crash/pass report from the platform.

I am trying to build a shield using unsupervised machine learning that will help me identify/classify these images as malicious or not. I have the binary data of these files, but I have no clue of what featureSet/patterns I can identify from this, because visually these images could be anything. (I need to be able to find feature set from the binary data)

*I need some advise on the tools/methods I could use for automatic feature extraction from this binary data*; feature sets which I can use with unsupervised learning algorithms such as Kohenen's SOM etc.

I am new to this, any help would be great!

Comment: What do you mean with *binary data* of an image? If you can view the image then you can retrieve the values of each pixel which are needed as features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think this is feasible.

The problem is that these are *old* exploits, and training on them will not tell you much about *future* exploits. Because this is an extremely unbalanced problem: no exploit uses the same thing as another. So even if you generate multiple files of the same type, you will in the end have likely a relevant single training case for example for each exploit.

Nevertheless, what you need to do is to extract features from the *file meta data*. This is where the exploits are, not in the actual image. As such, parsing the files is already much the area where the problem is, and your detection tool may become vulnerable to exactly such an exploit.

As the data may be *compressed*, a naive binary feature thing will not work, either.

Comment: thanks a ton for your answer! I figure I will have to change my approach to this. I was looking at some metadata extractors, I came across - Hachoir (python library). Any other suggestions on tools/libraries that I could use? Thanks :)

Comment: The problem is that the attacks usually are *against* the metadata extractors. So you cannot trust them, you'll also be vulnerable.

Comment: thats interesting. But then there must be some way this problem can be approached without compromising system security?

Comment: Well, for ensuring system security your best try is to use a sandbox, parse the file with all major parsers, and see if one of the parser crashes. The key thing is to use a strong sandbox.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I would like to ask you one more question though. What kind of features do you recommend I look at extracting from the image headers? Because the exploits in the headers will vary. What features should I be looking at extracting and feeding into ML algorithms? Thanks

Comment: Look for invalid values. Such as negative image sizes or just any kind of invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to look at the actual pixel data at all since the corruption most (almost certain) lay in the file header with it's different "chunks" (example for png, works differently but in the same way for other formats):

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header

It should be straight forward to choose features, make a program that reads all the header information from the file and if the information is missing and use this information as features. Still will be much smaller then the unnecessary raw image data.

Oh, and always start out with simpler algorithms like pca together with kmeans or something, and if they fail you should bring out the big guns.

Comment: It's somewhat misleading, but I think it's about the data after all. See the comment to my answer.

Comment: You think? Why does he mention: "These files when rendered on various platforms lead to warning/crash/pass report from the platform." ?

Comment: Nope, you're right. I've deleted my answer and retagged the question.

Comment: aaa okey, np :) sorry just wanted to see if I got everything right, kinda tired

Comment: wow, thanks for your answers! as I mentioned in one of the answers above, I guess I will have to change my approach to this. I was looking at hachoir (python library) for metadata extraction. Any other suggestions for tools I could use (either in python or java). cheers! :))

Comment: actually no, never worked with metadata on images, but: python > java :P