# Feature extraction from Image metadata

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, metadata, feature-extraction

I am working on a security problem, where I am trying to identify malicious images. I have to mine for attributes from images (most likely from the metadata) that can be fed in to Weka to run various machine learning algorithms, in order to detect malicious images.

Since the image metadata can be corrupted in various different ways, I am finding it difficult to identify the features to look at in the image metadata, which I can quantify for the learning algorithms.

I had earlier used information like pixel info etc using tools like ImageJ to help me classify images, however I am looking for a better way (with regards to the security) to identify and quantify features from the image/image-metadata.

Any suggestion on the tools and the features?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for Feature Extraction from Binary Data of Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385526/tools-for-feature-extraction-from-binary-data-of-images)

Comment: Take a look at Phil Harvey's EXIF Tool - http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before **this is not a learning problem**.

The problem is that **one exploit is *not* *similar* to another exploit**. They exploit individual, separate bugs in individual, different (!) libraries, things such as missing bounds checking. It's not so much a property of the file, but more of the library that uses it. 9 out of 10 libraries will not care. One will misbehave because of a programming error.

The best you can do to *detect* such files is to write the most *pedantic* and at the same time most *robust* format verifier you can come up with, and reject any image that doesn't 1000% fit the specifications. Assuming that the libraries do not have errors in processing images that are actually valid.

**I strongly would recommend you start with investigating how the exploits actually work.** Understanding what you are trying to "learn" may guide you to some way of detecting them in general (or understanding why there is no general detection possible ...).

Here is a simple example of the ideas of how *one or two* of these exploits might work:

Assume we have a very simple file format, like BMP. For compression, it has support for a simple run length encoding, so that identical pixels can be efficiently stored as (`count x color` pairs). Does not work well with photos, but is quite compact for line art. Consider the following image data:

```
Width: 4
Height: 4
Colors: 1 = red, 2 = blue, 3 = green, 4 = black
Pixel data: 2x1 (red), 4x2 (blue), 2x3, 5x1, 1x0, 4x1
```

How many errors in the file do you spot? They may cause some trusting library code to fail, but any modern library (written with knowing about this kind of attacks and with knowing that files may have been corrupted due to transmission and hard disk errors) should just skip that and maybe even produce a partial image. See, maybe it was *not* an attack, but just a programming error in the program that produced the image...

Heck, even not every out-of-bounds use must be an attack. Think of CDs. Everybody used "overburning" at some time to put more data on a CD than was meant by the specifications. Yes, *some* drive might crash because you overburned a CD. But I wouldn't consider all the CDs with more than 650 MB to be attacks, just because they broke the Yellow Book specifications of what a CD is.